# Combining table sorting and filtering

Tags: sorting, jsf, filter, richfaces

I'm trying to create a sortable table using Richfaces version 3.3.3.
I've managed to implement table sorting and filtering using the built-in functionality. The built in filtering doesn't fit my needs, so I've implemented the external filtering.

Here's what I got in my front end so far:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{publicServiceList.serviceList}"
                id="serviceTable" var="_service" rows="20" reRender="ds"
                sortMode="single"
                columnClasses="listItemLink, listItem, listeItem, listItemLink"
                headerClass="listHeader" rowClasses="odd, even"
                styleClass="listHeaderBackground">

<f:facet name="header">
    <rich:columnGroup>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText
                value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.SERVICENAME']}" />
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <h:outputText
                value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.DESCRIPTION']}" />
        </rich:column>
    </rich:columnGroup>
</f:facet>

<rich:column filterBy="#{_service.title}" filterEvent="onkeyup"
    filterValue="#{publicServiceList.currentTitleFilterValue}"
    sortBy="#{_service.title}">
    <s:link view="/public/PublicService.xhtml"
        value="#{_service.title}" propagation="none"
        id="publicServiceView">
        <f:param name="serviceId" value="#{_service.id}" />
    </s:link>
</rich:column>

<rich:column filterMethod="#{publicServiceList.filterDescription}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:inputText
            value="#{publicServiceList.currentDescriptionFilterValue}"
            id="input">
            <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="serviceTable , ds"
                ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="700"
                oncomplete="setCaretToEnd(event);" />
        </h:inputText>
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{_service.shortDescription}" />
</rich:column>

<f:facet name="footer">
    <rich:datascroller id="ds" renderIfSinglePage="false"></rich:datascroller>
</f:facet>
```

This code generates the following:
[image: Generated table]

The filtering and sorting works just fine, but the layout doesn't seem to work when using the columnGroup element and I can't get it to work when mixing and matching filterValue/filterBy attributes in the columnGroup element or the individual columns.

When I use only built-in filtering and sorting, this is what it looks like:

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{publicServiceList.serviceList}"
            id="serviceTable" var="_service" rows="20" reRender="ds"
            sortMode="single"
            columnClasses="listItemLink, listItem, listeItem, listItemLink"
            headerClass="listHeader" rowClasses="odd, even"
            styleClass="listHeaderBackground">

<rich:column filterBy="#{_service.title}" filterEvent="onkeyup"
    filterValue="#{publicServiceList.currentTitleFilterValue}"
    sortBy="#{_service.title}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.SERVICENAME']}" />
    </f:facet>
    <s:link view="/public/PublicService.xhtml"
        value="#{_service.title}" propagation="none"
        id="publicServiceView">
        <f:param name="serviceId" value="#{_service.id}" />
    </s:link>
</rich:column>

<rich:column filterBy="#{_service.description}"
    filterEvent="onkeyup"
    filterValue="#{publicServiceList.currentDescriptionFilterValue}"
    sortBy="#{_service.shortDescription}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.DESCRIPTION']}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{_service.shortDescription}" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column filterBy="#{_service.keywordString}"
    filterEvent="onkeyup"
    filterValue="#{publicServiceList.currentKeywordFilterValue}"
    sortBy="#{_service.keywordString}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.KEYWORDS']}" />
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText value="#{_service.keywordString}" />
</rich:column>

<rich:column filterBy="#{_service.organization}"
    filterEvent="onkeyup"
    filterValue="#{publicServiceList.currentOrganizationFilterValue}"
    sortBy="#{_service.organization}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText
            value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.ORGANIZATION']}" />
    </f:facet>
    <s:link view="/public/PublicOrganization.xhtml"
        value="#{_service.organization.organizationName}"
        propagation="none" id="publicOrganizationView">
        <f:param name="organizationId"
            value="#{_service.organization.organizationId}" />
    </s:link>
</rich:column>

<f:facet name="footer">
    <rich:datascroller id="ds" renderIfSinglePage="false"></rich:datascroller>
</f:facet>
```

And here is the result of the above jsf. I would like my first solution to display like this, but it doesn't seem to be possible since I can't declare two child elements to my facet. Implementing external filtering requires that I myself add inputText element for filtering and outputText to display the columns name.

[image]

The only flaw with this approach is  that the built in filter is limited:

> This is built-in feature. It uses "startsWith" function to make filtering.

[Source](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=usage&cid=1206068)

Is there any way to filtering and sorting? I haven't managed with external + external or external / built-in. Is there some way I could override  the functionality of the built-in filter to use "containsIgnoreCase" function instead?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Give me a heads up if you need any more information. I've used these two examples as my sources:

- [Table sorting](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/sortingFeature.jsf?c=sorting&tab=usage)
- [Table filtering](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=ex-usage&cid=1206084)

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, the layout? Or is the sorting/filtering not working together?

Comment: @Makhiel The problem is that I can't implement external filtering together with the built-in sorting. As shown in the first image, this displays incorrectly. When using the built-in sorting and filtering (second image), all that is needed is to declare some attributes in the column tag and it's finished. However, implementing the external filtering requires that I declare my columns in a columnGroup to set header names (Tjänst/Description). I then have to declare an inputText in the same column, and sortBy attribute which somehow brakes the layout.

Comment: "However, implementing the external filtering requires that I declare my columns in a columnGroup to set header names" - there is no such requirement.

Comment: I interpreted it as a problem since I cant define both my inputText element for user input and outputText to display the column name in a single facet. How would I go about solving that without using columnGroup?

Comment: Why can't you put the text and input together? The built-in has it like that. By columnGroup I assume you mean the table header, if you want the controls in there you cannot use the built-ins because they're tied to the individual columns.

Comment: @Makhiel So I finally solved this. A header only supports one child element, so I can't outputText and inputText in the same facet. I tried to use a panelGroup, but clicking in the inputField triggered the sorting since both components are handled as the columns header. My final solution is using built-in sortBy and a filterExpression in another table above my initial table. It's not pretty, but it does the work.

Comment: You can use `onclick="Event.stop(event);"` to stop the sort from triggering, just like it is done in the [other example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dataTable.jsf?tab=modifiableDataModel).

Comment: @Makhiel Well that is certainly a more elegant solution. When I inspect the page I can see  the onclick attribute in the input field, but I can't see any markup in the jsf. It seems their columns are generated automatically and that the onclick is something you get automatically? I'd like to mark your response as the correct answer instead. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my final solution. It does the job, but it's not pretty. I've removed all other columns for brevity.
The reasons for doing it like this are:

- [Using built-in filtering is limited to startsWith()](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=usage&cid=1239663)
- Mixing external filtering and built-in sorting makes the inputText behave as part of the header, meaning that clicking it makes it lose focus and instead sort the entire column.
- [External sorting requires you to set selfSort to false, and use an external sorting component.](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/sortingFeature.jsf?tab=ex-usage&cid=1239676) Not what I was looking to achieve.

To understand what I mean by built-in and external, these two examples contain tabs at the top with examples of both:
 - [Table Sorting](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/sortingFeature.jsf?c=sorting&tab=usage)
 - [Table Filtering](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=usage&cid=1239663)

```
<h:form>
<rich:dataTable
    columnClasses="listItemLink, listItem, listItem, listItemLink"
    styleClass="listHeaderBackground" headerClass="listHeader">
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:inputText
                value="#{publicServiceList.currentTitleFilterValue}">
                <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="serviceTable , ds"
                    ignoreDupResponses="true" requestDelay="200"
                    oncomplete="setCaretToEnd(event);" />
            </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>

<rich:dataTable value="#{publicServiceList.serviceList}"
    id="serviceTable" var="_service" rows="20" reRender="ds"
    sortMode="single"
    columnClasses="listItemLink, listItem, listItem, listItemLink"
    headerClass="listHeader" rowClasses="odd, even"
    styleClass="listHeaderBackground">

    <rich:column
        filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(_service.title, publicServiceList.currentTitleFilterValue)}"
        sortBy="#{_service.title}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText
                value="#{messages['public.page.service_A-Z.list.title.SERVICENAME']}" />
        </f:facet>
        <s:link view="/public/PublicService.xhtml"
            value="#{_service.title}" propagation="none"
            id="publicServiceView">
            <f:param name="serviceId" value="#{_service.id}" />
        </s:link>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Final output:
[image]

Hope this helps someone.